# Create Page To Count Comments For Each Post In Wordpress Site

Tags: php, functions, pages, comments

I'm trying to count the number of live comments on each post. I would like to extract them on a custom page like `http://example.com/count.php` and have them output like this:

```
http://example.com/the-post-url-with-3-comments/    3
http://example.com/the-post-url-with-no-comments/   0
http://example.com/the-post-url-with-12-comments/   12
```

The spacing between all the posts don't matter quite as much, I just need the two columns with all my posts and number of approved comments.

I have come close to doing this with [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99264/cant-show-comments-count-per-post-outside-loop) and using `echo get_comment_count( 149 );` but it only uses one post at a time. I would like to extract all the posts.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do. Put this code in your **functions.php** file.

The logic is pretty straightforward.

- Get all posts with `get_posts()`.
- Iterate over all post, extract comments count and permalink of current post and
- Print out the results.

.

```
add_action( 'init', 'get_comments_count' ); // Hook to init, elsewhere or use directly in your code
function get_comments_count() {

  $all_posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1 ) );

  foreach( $all_posts as $current_post ){

    $comments_count = get_comment_count( $current_post->ID );
    $permalink = get_permalink( $current_post->ID );

    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a> - %s<br>', $permalink, $permalink, $comments_count['total_comments'] );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It will display comment count of each post in post loop. It also provide link to comments.

```
<a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number('0 Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
</a>
```